# How to trigger data upload from Cloud Storage to BigQuery from Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

An api server is running on Kubernetes Engine (GKE). Users can upload relatively small sets of data (~100mb, multiple .csv with the same data structure) from client applications to Cloud Storage (GCS). Once upload is complete, i need to import all data from all new .csv files to a single existing BigQuery table with some user-specific params (mark each row with user id may be or so). Order doesn't matter.

Google docs are offering GUI-based solutions and command line solutions for this. Though, i assume, there is a way to trigger upload and track it's progress from the GKE-based server itself. How do i do that?

Not sure if this is important: GKE api server is written on NodeJS.

Comment: Can you define the CSV file as a federated table (as part of a BigQuery query job) and then run a query like `SELECT *, <user_id> FROM MyCsvTable;`? You can specify to append to the existing table as part of the query job.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard you mean "query from csv without uploading it to BigQuery"? I think this will be much less efficient, than dealing with this data in BigQuery itself after upload

Comment: It depends on the model I guess. If you want to process many 100MB files at once, then I agree that loading the CSV files into BigQuery first is the better choice. For a "real-time" solution, you could use federated tables. In any case, have you tried using the BigQuery API from NodeJS? It sounds like that's what you need to use.

Comment: i haven't found solution in "BigQuery API from NodeJS"

Comment: This is the code sample from the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-import-gcs-file-nodejs

Comment: thanks @ElliottBrossard, looks like it. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, added an answer with the code sample and some relevant links. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of uploading a file to GCS, taken from the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-import-gcs-file-nodejs). You can configure the job as you need; there are a few references on that page and a [link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/tables.js) with additional functionality:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client libraries
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// The project ID to use, e.g. "your-project-id"
// const projectId = "your-project-id";

// The ID of the dataset of the table into which data should be imported, e.g. "my_dataset"
// const datasetId = "my_dataset";

// The ID of the table into which data should be imported, e.g. "my_table"
// const tableId = "my_table";

// The name of the Google Cloud Storage bucket where the file is located, e.g. "my-bucket"
// const bucketName = "my-bucket";

// The name of the file from which data should be imported, e.g. "file.csv"
// const filename = "file.csv";

// Instantiates clients
const bigquery = BigQuery({
  projectId: projectId
});

const storage = Storage({
  projectId: projectId
});

let job;

// Imports data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
bigquery
  .dataset(datasetId)
  .table(tableId)
  .import(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename))
  .then((results) => {
    job = results[0];
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

    // Wait for the job to finish
    return job.promise();
  })
  .then((results) => {
    // Get the job's status
    return job.getMetadata();
  }).then((metadata) => {
    // Check the job's status for errors
    const errors = metadata[0].status.errors;
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
      throw errors;
    }
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

After uploading, you can [run a query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-nodejs) that queries the newly uploaded CSV file(s) and appends the result to the desired destination table.